# Magento 2: dataprovider getData() get called twice losing my requestdata

Tags: magento2, url, parameter

In magento 2 I created a grid through UI components. It gets populated with my dataprovide class getData method:

```
public function getData()
{
    $questionSetId = $this->request->getParam('questionset_id');

    if (!$this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
        $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('questionset_id', $questionSetId);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
    }

    return $this->getCollection()->toArray();;

}
```

I don't know if its normal that this function gets called twice, I have a param `question_set` in my url but the second time `getData()` gets called, `$questionSetId` becomes `null` which means that no data will be loaded because of the use of a filter.

What am I missing here?

PS. Magento 2.1.9

Comment: How did you get around this?

Comment: @vitoriodachef If recall correctly i used a data persistor for setting the data